# Get tag value using minidom in dynamic tree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, minidom

I have a xml file which doesn't have the same tags every time in some deep levels.

For example, this is a part of the xml structure, where `<openie>` is located in

`root > document > sentences > sentence > openie`

and I want to get values from `<text>` tag for each `sentence`

```
<openie>
  <triple confidence="1.000">
    <subject begin="1" end="2">
      <text>customer</text>
      <lemma>customer</lemma>
    </subject>
    <relation begin="2" end="3">
      <text>enters</text>
      <lemma>enter</lemma>
    </relation>
    <object begin="3" end="6">
      <text>their order number</text>
      <lemma>they order number</lemma>
    </object>
  </triple>
</openie>
```

I have started with this approach but I got stuck at the point where the XML has different tags, ie. `subject`, `relation` and `object`. And the structure in each `openie` can change, for example there can be some other tag along with these three I mentioned and it also can have `<text>` tag.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def parse_xml():
    xmldoc = minidom.parse('./tmp/nlp_output.xml')
    sentencesNode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('sentences')
    for sentenceNode in sentencesNode:
        for openIeNode in sentenceNode.childNodes:
            for tripleNode in openIeNode.childNodes:
              #what now?
```

Comment: Could you also post the other *openie* node (with other tags)? And how do you want the output to look like (for this node  and for the other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of your problem need, which is

- I want to get values from **< text >** tag for each sentence ?

---

There is no need to keep `track` of `different tags` or child-nodes every time. Here is simple workaround:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xml_doc = minidom.parse('./tmp/nlp_output.xml')

#  To get Number of available tags, you want to search :
item_list = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName('text')
print("Number of text-tags:", len(item_list), '\n')

for text_Elem in item_list:
    text_value = ''.join([node.data for node in text_Elem.childNodes])
    print('Required Value:', text_value)
```

By using this technique, you'll get **Exact**  `tag value` as required in your case.  To learn in detail about XML-parsing visit reference: [How-to-Parse-XML-in-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python).

---

Here is **output** for given XML-File i.e `nlp_output.xml`,

```
 - Number of text-tags: 3 

 - Required Value: customer

 - Required Value: enters 

 - Required Value: their order number
```